# Realm Results with custom ordering

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

How can I get a realm `Results` with a custom ordering in React Native? I know I can use `.sorted()`, but if I want the results in a [sortable list](https://github.com/deanmcpherson/react-native-sortable-listview), what options do I have to reorder them freely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the order of the elements of a `Realm.Results`. You can manipulate a `Realm.List` using `splice()` but that might be cumbersome.

As an alternative, you can add an extra property which you sort on. If you change the value of that property, the `Realm.Results` will automatically be resorted for you.